# Join and concat results on series of NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, join, concatenation

I need help on combining together two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [100, 120, 150, 130]}, index=[2, 4, 5, 6])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': [200,230,210,220,245,260], Y: [300,330,300,360,310,390]}, index=[1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

I need to obtain 
df3 =

```
index    X      Y       A    
2       230    330     100  
4       220    360     120
5       245    310     150
6       260    390     130
```

However, when I used concat([df2,df1],axis=1)`, I got a bunch of NaNs on Column A:

```
print (pd.concat([df2,df1],axis=1))
     X    Y      A
1  200  300    NaN
2  230  330    NaN
3  210  300    NaN
4  220  360    NaN
5  245  310    NaN
6  260  390    NaN
```

Which should be the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected, because aligned `DataFrame` by index values in [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) or [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
print (pd.concat([df2,df1],axis=1))
     X    Y      A
1  200  300    NaN
2  230  330  100.0 <-index 2 from df2 is aligned with row with index 2 in df1
3  210  300    NaN
4  220  360  120.0
5  245  310  150.0
6  260  390  130.0
```

EDIT:

It seems your index values have different `dtype`s:

```
df2.index = df2.index.astype(str)

print (df1.index)
Int64Index([2, 4, 5, 6], dtype='int64')

print (df2.index)
Index(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], dtype='object')

print (pd.concat([df2,df1],axis=1))
       X      Y      A
1  200.0  300.0    NaN
2  230.0  330.0    NaN
3  210.0  300.0    NaN
4  220.0  360.0    NaN
5  245.0  310.0    NaN
6  260.0  390.0    NaN
2    NaN    NaN  100.0
4    NaN    NaN  120.0
5    NaN    NaN  150.0
6    NaN    NaN  130.0
```

And solution is convert index values:

```
df2.index = df2.index.astype(int)
print (pd.concat([df2,df1],axis=1))
     X    Y      A
1  200  300    NaN
2  230  330  100.0
3  210  300    NaN
4  220  360  120.0
5  245  310  150.0
6  260  390  130.0
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the indexing is crucial for my analysis. Is there any way to keep it?

Comment: @pabrao - Can you add to question expected output? Because seems I dont understand, what you need.

Comment: Exactly the output from print (pd.concat([df2,df1],axis=1)). However, my column A is full of NaNs, instead of the actual numbers.

Comment: df1: dtype='object' - Index(['2','4','5',...])

Comment: df2: dtype='int64' - Int64Index([  1,   2,   3,   ...])

Comment: Worked! Cheers!

Comment: @pabrao - Supeer, Nice day!